# How to match a characters but not if they are strictly enclosed in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

**SCOPE**

Lets say we have a string `hello how are you dog? "d" I am "good" "g" ha good`

**REQUIREMENT**

I want a regex which gives the occurence of d or g but not when they are strictly(no other character) enclosed in quotes.

So, in the above string the matched occurences would be (enclosed in {})
`hello how are you {d}o{g}? "d" I am "{g}oo{d}" "g" ha {g}oo{d}`

*EDIT*

I am trying something like this:

```
//constructing a regex
re = RegExp(`(d|g)`, 'g')
newString = ""
'hello how are you dog? "d" I am "good" "g" ha good'
.split(re).map((word, index) => {       
    if (word.match(re) != null) {
       console.log("match")
       newString += "|" //replacement character
    } else {
       newString += word
    }
})
```

**NOTE**

I am working in Javascript. Couldn't come up with a pattern.

Thanks

Comment: You also need to add some code for a regex to work in this case. Are you extracting or replacing?

Comment: Just to let you know that I am replacing.

Comment: Removing or replacing with some other value? Please complete the test case in the question.

Comment: 'lookahead' ?= is good for this scenario. :)

Comment: @user943702 It doesn't work in javascript perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

Using `string`'s `replace`, using *function* method, and the regex

```
("[^"]*"|[^dg])|.
```

you can check if the capture matches anything. If not the match is the `d` or `g` you want to replace/remove/transform (or whatever ;). In the example I make it uppercase.

**Explanation:**

The regex first tries to match a double quoted string - `"[^"]*"`. If that matches it's captures. If it isn't, it tries to match, and capture, a character **other** than `d` or `g` - `[^dg]`.

If the one of the above matches, it's sent to the function as parameter `b`.

If none of the matches, the complete match is sent as parameter `a`, and that would be the the final alternation, outside the parentheses `.`.

So the function either gets a *valid* character/string in the `b` parameter, or an *invalid* one in `a`. If `b` is undefined, act and do *whatever* on `a`, otherwise just return `b`.

```js
var str = 'hello how are you dog? "d" I am "good" "g" ha good';

document.write(str.replace(/("[^"]*"|[^dg])|./g, function(a, b) {
    if(b==undefined)
      return a.toUpperCase();
    return b;
  }));
```

Comment: I missed the "(no other character)" part :S - so this does a little more than asked for (handles d's and g' anywhere in a string), but still works when they're *alone*.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex that will match the substrings you do not need (those that you will replace), and match and capture what you need to keep. I assume you want to keep `"g"` and `"d"`. Use

```
/("[gd]")|[dg]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9cuu0/1)

And the code that will do the final job:

```js
var rx = /("[gd]")|[dg]/g;
var s = 'hello how are you dog? "d" I am "good" "g" ha good';
var res = s.replace(rx, function($0,$1) {
  return $1 ? $1 : "|";
});
console.log(res); // => hello how are you |o|? "d" I am "|oo|" "g" ha |oo|
```

So, the `("[gd]")` matches and captures `"g"` or `"d"` into Group 1 and if it matches, the value is pasted back during replacement (see `$1 ? $1`), else, any `d` or `g` in other contexts are matched with `[dg]` and then replaced in the replace callback method.

Answer (score 0):

summarize requirements

- at least 2 letters in quote
- includes a d or a g

Then regexp = `/"(?=g|d)[^"]{2,}"/gi`

1. starts with a double quote
2. lookahead search for a g or d
3. there should be 2+ letters follows (includes the g or d)
4. ends with a double quote

test

```
(`no quote = dog god d g 
 1 letter only = "d" "g"  
 2+ letters = "go" "do" "dog" "god", "GoOD"
`).match(/"(?=g|d)[^"]{2,}?"/gi)
// ["go", "do", "dog", "god", "GoOD"]
// then do what you want..
```